# Git Change Head to certain commit will not change data in the file

Tags: git, github, tfs

I'm working on a C# Project that use git as the version control system. One of member commit old version of project(backup) to the remote server. So, many functions are deleted. I changed head of the repository using

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

It changed head of the project. But content inside the files are remain same.
How can I undo last commit update files also??

Comment: Maybe double-check the commit you deemed as good. You could have to search further up the tree if you happened to take a too recent (and corrupted) one. Also, might be useful to consider a [bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

Comment: Can you add the output that you get after typing git reflog

Comment: I deleted all files in the remote repository and push my backup folder.